# Control Panel Assistance - Created

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a 'control panel' in excel.

The first part of the project I am trying to get right is the ability to copy a series of information to other sheets based upon a cells value.

For example:

Date of Entry   Month Due   Date Due    S/O or SOM  Bolt Ons    Broadband   Mobile Acquisition  Mobile Retention    Open, Posted

This is where the user enters the information to record. Based on the Month Due which is written in the same format as my tabs I.e. May 2013, Jun 2013 etc I am trying to get this to copy the information to the corresponding sheet on the next available line.

The lines start C13 (C13: J13) on each page. There are approx 25 tabs.

Is this possible? I have found codes that I can use to copy to another sheet ie. For 2 sheet workbooks. But this is not quite what I am after.

Part two of this task is a option beneath this that I am also failing to make work.
This part is to update their information previously entered. Only 1 part needs updating and that is the Open/Closed/Posted part.
I have spaces to enter the month, the S/O or SOM number (like a reference) and the updated status. Essentially this function would search for the reference number and paste the new status in J13 for example of J144 depending on where it was.

I'm unsure what I should be changing to make the macros work.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, this is what you need to do.  Declare `Worksheet` and `Range` variables for the source & destination data. Then, set the destiantion cell's value = to the source cell's value.

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws1 as Worksheet  'Source worksheet
Dim ws2 as Worksheet  'Destination worksheet
Dim rng1 as Range      'source data range
Dim cl as Range  'cell variable
Dim rng2 as Range      'destination data range
Dim r as Long 'row counter

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Modify as needed'

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("C13:J13")

    'assuming your dates & worksheets are consistently named, and the date is in column D:
    Set ws2 = Sheets(Cstr(rng1.Cells(2).Value)) '

    'Get the last line in column C on destination sheet
    r = 1+ ws2.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row 

    'Set the destination range, assuming column C:
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("C" & r & ":J" & r & ")

    'Now, set the values in the second range equal to the first range
    rng2.Value = rng.Value



End Sub
```